# Schedule Auto Menu Changes in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, menu, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

Is there a way to have menu links to automatically change based on the time.  I have a page that has different events happening at different times.  I want to have one button on the menu for "Main Event", but schedule it to change what page it links to at a certain times of the day.

Main Event - Link 1 
Main Event - Link 2 (change to link 2 at 10:00) 
Main Event - Link 3 (change to link 3 at 11:00)

Comment: hi and welcome to SO! please provide the community here with some code you already have started to write so you can get some help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a WordPress shortcode and use the shortcode to echo the links.

```
function link_on_time() { 
    $mainEventLink = "Link 1";
    $currentTime = date('H:i');
    $link2Time = date('10:00');
    $link3Time = date('11:00');
    if ($currentTime >= $link2Time && $currentTime < $link3Time)
    {
        $mainEventLink = "Link 2";
    }
    else if ($currentTime >= $link3Time)
    {
        $mainEventLink = "Link 3";
    }

    return $mainEventLink;
}
add_shortcode('mainEventLink', 'link_on_time');
```